# Java If value is greater than perform

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, int

I have this dynamic Pages which count change as per data. 
I have to click on next page each time one page test is completed go to next page.
To do so I have Test script which will capture page count from the application. 
JAVA code I use as below I don't understand where its wrong as I don't get any error message

```
// Page 1 is always present     
        Reporter.log("Successfully rendered View Portfolios Page 1");
    Add_Log.info("Successfully rendered View Portfolios Page 1");

//This is fetching page count from the application which I convert to Int
    String entriesTxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//label[contains(@class,'pf-pageNo-label')])[2]")).getText().trim();
    String[] aEntriesText = entriesTxt.split(" ");
    String totalEntriesText = aEntriesText[aEntriesText.length - 1];
    int result = Integer.parseInt(totalEntriesText);    
    System.out.println(result);
            // Page 2
            // This if Page count is great than 1 then perform below action
    if (result > 1) {
    pagenew(driver, Filters[1]);
    Reporter.log("Successfully rendered View Portfolios Page 2");
    Add_Log.info("Successfully rendered View Portfolios Page 2");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
    // Page 3
            // This if Page count is great than 2 then perform below action
    if (result < 2) {
    pagenew(driver, Filters[2]);
    Reporter.log("Successfully rendered View Portfolios Page 3");
    Add_Log.info("Successfully rendered View Portfolios Page 3");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
```

With above code it is rendering all page this statement is not working 
     if (result > 1)
I Expect that page 2 should not render if result = 1

Comment: Do you see line “Succession rendered View Portfolios page 2” getting logged ??

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the test and start it in debug mode. Walk through the steps watching for where the execution deviates from the expected flow then research why. Once you do that, if you still don't understand... edit your question with the results and your updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that instead of

```
...
if (result < 2) {
...
```

You wanted to write

```
...
if (result > 2) {
...
```

And because of that your page 3 is rendered even if the result is 1.